# SonarQube 5.1 does not display unit test coverage results on the dashboard

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I have upgraded my [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) from 3.7 to 5.1 now. Issue is earlier I used to get all the unit test,integration test coverage report all fine on the dashboard. However, post the upgrade from 3.7 to 5.1 I do not get unit test coverage report anymore on the dashboard. I continue to get integration test coverage report like before. The reason to do the upgrade was that we moved from java 7 to java 8  as older version of [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) didn't support java 8. Please advise on how to resolve the issue as I have no clue until now.

Comment: Please add information how you build project and which tool do you use to generate code coverage. You might be interested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588656/not-getting-the-coverage-on-new-code-in-sonar-dashboard

Comment: I have a jenkins job that trigers a maven target sonar:sonar for the sonar build. The pom.xml has <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin> <sonar.branch>${project.scm.tag}</sonar.branch><sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/test/resources/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath> <plugins><plugin><groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId><version>2.17</version></plugin>

Answer (score 1):

You need to add tool (e.g jacoco) which generates code coverage report. SonarQube only analyse data generated by other tools (e.g. jacoco.exec, *.class etc). Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31590608/4944847